# OnLocationChanged method not called in MyLocationOverlay when Gps is Off

Tags: java, android, gps, provider, mylocationoverlay

On the documantation it says mylocationoverlay onlocationchanged method uses both gps and network provider when ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission defined. When Gps is on everything is fine, onlocationchanged working but when i close gps onlocationchanged never called.
Is there any problem in my class? Do i have to implement locationlistener or locationmanager?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class FLOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {

public FLOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView) {
    super(context, mapView);

    enableCompass();
    enableMyLocation();
}

@Override           
public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     /***/
}

@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView map) {

            /***/

}

}
```

Comment: You probobly need to move a long way (> 1km) for the non Gps location to spot any change.  How far did you move?

Comment: Not much really, but didn't it has to give a first fix at start? Or do i have to use another way for the first fix before onLocationChanged?

Comment: I use getLastKnowenLocation or something like that on LocationManager manager to initalise a value.

Comment: I was using getlastfix but sometimes it returns null when getLastKnownLocation is not, so i made a methot which checks getlastfix, getlastknownlocation both gps and network, it's ok for me now.

Comment: Thanks Ifor write your post as an answer please.